# How do i create switches from table data?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, homekit

For example, if i save a plug called "Lamp" in my home kit.How do i code it in my watch kit such that for every entitiy saved in home kit will create a new switch that has the name of the plug?

Answer (score 0):

Either upload and fetch data from your backend at watch kit extension or use [App Group](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions) or `WKInterfaceController` for `openParentApplication:reply:`

Hope it's what u seeking for